# Qt signal for changed hashmap

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a hashmap **ReferenceMap** in a Qt serial terminal program.

The program receives a key to **ReferenceMap** in form of a reference followed by a value. It then uses the Qt hashmap insert function to insert the value. It's very neat and I would like to keep that part of the program.

The problem is that I would like to to do different things when different new values are coming in. I therefore would like to emit a signal when a value associated with a special place in the referencemap is changed.

According to the guide below, an object that emits a signal can easily be created. 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

I think I got a solution, however, and want to discuss wether it's a neat way or not.

I could create a class in like this

```
class Sfloat : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Sfloat(QObject *parent = 0);

    float Get();
    void SetValue(float value);

private:
float MyFloat;


signals:
void ValueChanged(float newValue);

public slots:

};
```

The ReferenceMap could then be set to contain references to SFloat object like,

ReferenceMap(Key, &SFloat).

When I have the key, I could get the object reference, call SetValue() and a signal would be emitted. However, is this the best way to solve it?

Comment: i personally like it, when the storage unit is only a storage unit. usually i have a storage controller class that handles what is stored where and what to do if something changed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a good idea. You are wrapping every float of your hash with a QObject which sounds very heavy to me.

You can hap the whole HashMap inside the QObject and emit the signal from there when the value you are interested in has changed.

```
class MyHashMap : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyHashMap(QObject *parent = 0);

    float Get(const QString& key) const;
    void SetValue(const QString& key, float value)
    {
      // only emit value changed if the value has actually changed
            QHashMap<QString, float>::iterator it = myHashMap.find(key);
            if(it != myHashMap.end()){
                if(it.value != value){
                    myHashMap[key] = value;
                    emit ValueChanged(key, value);
                }
            }
    }

private:
QHashMap<QString, float> myHashMap;

signals:
void ValueChanged(const QString& key, float newValue);
};
```

According to your comment, you want to update a label when a value has changed. Simply add all the labels to a QHashMap, then connect the ValueChanged signal to a slot that updates the right label:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0)
        {
            ...
            ...
            myLabels["label1"] = myLabel1;
            myLabels["label2"] = myLabel2;
            QObject::connect(myLabels, SIGNAL(ValueChanged(const QString&, float)), 
                this, OnValueChanged(const QString&, float));
        }

public slots:
    void OnValueChanged(const QString& key, float newValue){
        QHashMap<QString, QLabel*>::iterator it = myLabels.find(key);
        if(it != myLabels.end()){
            it.value()->setText(QString::number(newValue));
        }
    }

private:
QHashMap<QString, QLabel*> myLabels;
};
```

Comment: Well thats seems like a neat start! 

The thing is then that I want to connect each ValueChanged signal with different actions, eg. change a specific text label. 

Should I aim for connecting the key in the emitted signal with perhaps a hashmap with function pointers that does the things I want? 

Or just call  a function that prints all values in MyHash each time a value is changed? 

There are so many ways to do these things, and I'm looking for the "best" way.

Comment: I edited the answer according to your comment. You might wanna update the question.

Comment: Thank you for great answers! 

What do you generally think about the concept of storing function pointers in a map?

Comment: I don't see any technical problem in storing function pointers in a map but it sounds to me like there is probably a better alternative. Plus, in a gui application where performance is not critical, I would favour using polymorphism or if/switch statements instead of function pointers.